# async/await for high performance server applications?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

the new async/await keywords in C# 5 look very promising but I read an article about the performance impact on those applications since the compiler will generate a quite complex state machine for async methods.

Async-programming using these keywords is so much easier but is it as good as say SocketAsyncEventArgs for Sockets ?

Second question: Are asynchronous IO methods like Stream.WriteAsync really asynchronous (Completion Ports on .Net or epoll/poll on Mono) or are these methods cheap wrappers for pushing a write call to a threadpool ?

Third question: Beside the SynchronizationContext of an UI application, is there a way to implement some kind of sinlge-threaded context ? Something like an event loop so that finished tasks continues on the main thread ?
I discovered the Nito.AsyncEx library, but I'm not quite sure whether or not this is what i need.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`async` itself is quite performant. A ton of work went into this.

In general, on the server side you're concerned about `async` I/O. I'm going to ignore `async` CPU-bound methods because the `async` overhead will get lost in the noise anyway.

Asynchronous I/O will increase your memory usage per request, but it'll reduce your thread usage per request. So you end up winning (except borderline pathological corner cases). This is true for all asynchronous I/O, including `async`.

`await` was designed with a pattern - not just the `Task` type - so if you need to squeeze out as much performance as possible, you can.

> I read an article about the performance impact on those applications since the compiler will generate a quite complex state machine for async methods.

The [article you read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) by Stephen Toub is excellent. I also recommend the [Zen of Async video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T) (also by Stephen Toub).

> Async-programming using these keywords is so much easier but is it as good as say SocketAsyncEventArgs for Sockets ?

First, understand that `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is more scalable because it reduces memory garbage. The simpler way to use `async` sockets will generate more memory garbage, but since `await` is pattern-based you can [define your own `async`-compatible wrappers for the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) (as seen on Stephen Toub's blog... I'm sensing a pattern here ;). This allows you to squeeze every ounce of performance out.

Though it's usually better in the long run to design a scale-out system rather than twisting the code to avoid a few memory allocations. IMHO.

> Second question: Are asynchronous IO methods like Stream.WriteAsync really asynchronous (Completion Ports on .Net or epoll/poll on Mono) or are these methods cheap wrappers for pushing a write call to a threadpool ?

I don't know about Mono. On .NET, *most* asynchronous I/O methods are based on a completion port. The `Stream` class is a notable exception. The `Stream` base class will do a "cheap wrapper" by default, but allows derived classes to override this behavior. `Stream`s that come from network communications always override this to provide truly asynchronous I/O. `Stream`s that deal with files only override this **if** the stream was constructed explicitly for asynchronous I/O.

> Third question: Beside the SynchronizationContext of an UI application, is there a way to implement some kind of single-threaded context ?

ASP.NET also has a `SynchronizationContext`, so if you're using ASP.NET you're already set.

If you are doing your own socket-based server (e.g., a Win32 service), then you *could* use the `AsyncContext` type in my AsyncEx library. But it doesn't sound like this is what you'd actually want. `AsyncContext` will create a single-threaded context on the current thread. But the true power of `async` for server applications comes from scaling *requests* instead of *threads*.

Consider how the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` works: as each *request* comes in, it grabs a thread pool thread and constructs a `SynchronizationContext` (for that *request*). When that request has asynchronous work to do, it registers with the `SynchronizationContext` and the thread running that request returns to the thread pool. Later, when the asynchronous work completes, it grabs a thread pool thread (*any* thread), installs the existing `SynchronizationContext` on it, and continues processing that request. When the request is finally completed, its `SynchronizationContext` is disposed.

The key in that process is that when the request is waiting (`await`) asynchronous operations, there are *no* threads dedicated to that request. Since a *request* is considerably lightweight compared to a *thread*, this enables the server to scale better.

If you gave each of your requests a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` such as `AsyncContext`, this would bind a thread to each request even when it has nothing to do. That's hardly any better than a synchronous multithreaded server.

You may find my [MSDN article on `SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) useful if you want to tackle inventing your own `SynchronizationContext`. I also cover in that article how asynchronous methods "register" and "install" the context; this is done mostly-automatically by `async void` and `await` so you won't have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Very nice answer. I don't know if you are familiar with Netty (a Java network framework). There each client get its dedicated thread in a threadpool with a maximum of 4 - 8 threads depending on the available processor threads, to avoid context switch. If one thread gets too much pressure the clients are rearranged, but this is quite rare. In theory, this context switch should have an impact von scalability, shouldn't it ? You already convinced me that async/await is more than enough for my purposes but its just for my interest.

Comment: After a lot of test I think the async/await impl. of .NET4.5 is pretty amazing. Actually the *Async methods almost always perform as good as SocketAsyncEventArgs. Of course, my testings were kind of primitive but I think it shows the trend.

Answer (score 6):

1. If you're using it in the context of async IO it's a moot point.  The time spent on your database operation, file/network IO, etc. will be milliseconds at best.  The overhead of `async` will be microseconds at worst, if no nanoseconds.  Where you need to be careful is when you have a *lot* of operations that you are awaiting (as in thousands, tens of thousands, or more) and those operations are *very* quick.  When those async operations represent CPU bound work it's certainly possible for the overhead of using `await` to be at least noticeable.  Note that the code generated for the state machine is somewhat complex, in terms of human understand-ability, but state machines in general tend to perform rather well as a whole.
2. The methods are not just wrappers that block a thread pool thread, no.  That would defeat the purpose of what `await` represents.  Those methods don't block *any* thread and rely on OS hooks to complete the task.
3. Sure, you can create your own `SynchronizationContext` instead of relying entirely on an existing one provided by your UI framework.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3.aspx) is a great example.  Just be careful when using something like this; it's a good tool for the right task, but can be abused to find a more creating way of blocking when you should just be doing everything asynchronously.

Comment: About 1.: Lets assume we have lots of clients (2000 - 7000 maybe) with mostly IO bound operations like reading/writing files or accessing the database. Would such an massive amount of io bound tasks work in theory ? Or is this generally a bad pattern for a big server ?